# Tweepy get created_at of user as an unix timestamp

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to know when an `user` is created.  The following script gives the desired information:

```
import sys
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

USER_KEY = ''
USER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

   def on_data(self, data):
       tweet = json.loads(data)
       account_created = tweet['user']['created_at'] 
       print(account_created)


   def on_error(self, status):
       if status == 420:
           sys.stderr.write('Enhance Your Calm; The App Is Being Rate Limited For Making Too Many Requests')
           return True
       else:
           sys.stderr.write('Error {}n'.format(status))
           return True

 if __name__ == "__main__":
 listener =  StdOutListener()
 auth = OAuthHandler(USER_KEY, USER_SECRET)
 auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

 stream = Stream(auth, listener)
 stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=['Python'])
```

However, the output shows as follows:

```
Wed Mar 06 03:11:05 +0000 2019
```

How can I transform this to an UNIX-timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: (tested with python 3.6)

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('Wed Mar 06 03:11:05 +0000 2019', '%a %b %m %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
print(dt.timestamp())
```